# Can a comment provide structural support to a function?

Tags: java, rest

I have this comment in my code and when I remove it the function breaks. How and why would this comment prevent my code from running correctly?

I tried removing the comment, but it only works when the comment is there.

Comment: can you please provide the code or an example of the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

No, by definition, a "comment" has no impact on the function of code.

What you think is a comment may, in fact, be code. The most likely candidate for this sort of confusion is an annotation.

Java uses code annotations, which start with `@`, such as `@Override`, and these can affect code compilation or be retained and used at runtime. Confusion can arise because Java's "Javadoc" documentation syntax features tags, which also start with `@`. Furthermore, the tags and annotations can be named similarly and appear nearby, like `@param` and `@Param`, or `@deprecated` and `@Deprecated`.

Comment: Not worth answering before getting clarification, IMHO